# connect android to django locally

Tags: android, mysql, django, sockets, python-3.x

i'm trying to connect android app to django web server that both android device and django web server are using a same internet connection(both connected to same AP) and sending data that in my case it's Json file.

django web server should take the Json file and change the data stored in database(in my case MySQL and django runs on python3).
is there any way to Not use rest API?or using something like Socket programming in django?
remember i just want to send Json file in WLAN network.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sockets, but i think HTTP request are much more simple to work with, as django is WSGI based, and it doesn't support Sockets out of the box, you will need to use something like [Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.org) to handle sockets.